# JSON to ver strage cache issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im retriving data from my php and its working fine ,  the problem is that

`var myData` is getting cached and only updates if i refesh my page 2 times...

on my firebug i can see the post updates but when  i `console.log(myData);the data is the old one ..until i refresh..

[image]

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/mobile_read.php",    // path to remote script
    dataType: "JSON", 
    type: 'post',
    data:{
    id : id,
    eventos : eventos,

},                               // data set to retrieve JSON
    success: function (data) {                       // on success, do something...
        // grabbing my JSON data and saving it
        // to localStorage for future use.
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('myData1', JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});

var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData1'));

console.log(myData);

var arrayObjects = myData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to set and read mydata before the request/response is complete. Instead, move that into your success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/mobile_read.php",    // path to remote script
    dataType: "JSON", 
    type: 'post',
    data:{
    id : id,
    eventos : eventos,

},                               // data set to retrieve JSON
    success: function (data) {                       // on success, do something...
        // grabbing my JSON data and saving it
        // to localStorage for future use.
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('myData1', JSON.stringify(data));

        var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData1'));
        console.log(myData);
        var arrayObjects = myData;
    }
});
```